# Active Directory Account Operator Modifying Groups Which Inherit Privileged Groups

Tags: windows, active-directory

In Active Directory, if a member of the **Account Operators** group, by default, is possible to add myself to a group which is a member of the **Domain Admins** group?

For instance, I have a group named **Tier 3 Admins** which is member of **Domain Admins** group as shown in the image below:

[image: groups]

The account I control has access to the **Account Operators** group, but remembering that **Account Operators** group cannot modify Protected Groups such as **Domain Admins**, this should not be possible, right?

When testing, I find that this is not true, and I can indeed add myself to the **Tier 3 Admins** group. Does the Tier 3 Admins not inherit the ACLs of the protected group **Domain Admins**? How is this possible?

Below is an image of my user, jsmith, adding myself to the **Tier 3 Admins** group as **Account Operators**, thus gaining **Domain Admin** privileges.

[image]

Comment: - Have you reviewed the ACL on the AdminSDHolder object to confirm custom permissions weren't granted (if this group was covered)?
- Have you confirmed that the SDProp process has run recently?
- Have you confirmed that adminCount=1 on the 'Tier 3 Admins' group?
- Have you confirmed the SDProp process has run at least once since this 'Tier 3 Admins' was added to 'Domain Admins'?

Comment: It' could be a workaround in the privileged account provisioning process. Otherwise only members of Domain Admins could fulfill the membership request. The security principal members should still be protected though.

Answer (score 1):

Custom groups are not automatically added to the SDProp / AdminSDHolder process in Active Directory, only certain groups are included in this process (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory#protected-groups)

If you would like additional accounts to be added to this process, I would recommend (and actually use myself) a scheduled task that enumerates members of groups I want included in the process, and ensures the groups and their  recursive members have the admin-count attribute set to `1`.

A pseudo-code example:

```perl
'Tier 3 Admins' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive | Set-AdObject -Replace @{adminCount=1}
    Get-AdGroup -Identity $_ | Set-AdGroup -Replace @{adminCount=1}
}
```

Other thoughts and considerations:

- I really hate group names with spaces (but that is purely subjective and uninformative)
- You're using a privileged account 1) to use Invoke-Expression, 2) on a machine that is connnected to the internet, 3) on a machine that does not have a well defined execution policy, and 4) executing an unsigned script directly from the internet - a superfecta of "don't do this" for anybody wanting to try this at home.